# apache2 and passenger for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, passenger

i've installed passenger and then apache2. all is ok, but when i want to start passenger on 80 port it says:

```
*** ERROR ***
The address 0.0.0.0:80 is already in use by another process, perhaps another
Phusion Passenger Standalone instance.

If you want to run this Phusion Passenger Standalone instance on another port,
use the -p option, like this:

  passenger start -p 81
```

and on the 80 port works apache2. so they don't work together. and if i want to start passenger on 80 port, i have to disable apache2. is it correct? or how i should change settings?
now i've done:
/etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf :

```
PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.14                                                 
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
```

/etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.load :

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
```

and nothing else. thanks for your answers

Comment: Correct, only one process can listen on a port at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might not have exactly the correct terminology here, but Passenger is a module that runs inside Apache2.  You don't start them independently.  You just start Apache2 and then it loads up Passenger.

Comment: thanks..i got it..how i should config my apache2? i've viewed about 20 websites, but nothing is clear..